How to solve Load Cube Error on Oracle sql developer?
My team is beginner in advanced database systems, our professor assigned us to create a multidimensional model and create a cube with measures in oracle sql developer (enterprise version). The model is basic and just for practice (of course it is consistent). When we created our dimensions in the manager and tried to create our cube, we got the following error:

<ERROR>
<![CDATA[
XOQ-01930: La asignación de dimensionalidades del cubo no tiene ninguna dimensión asignada.]]>>
</ERROR> , las dimensiones están creadas y se compilan correctamente, ahí se puede ver las 10 filas añadidas, pero sale como si no existieran al momento de cargar.

The dimensions do the mapping from our physical model (sql generated in PowerDesigner).
The documentation Oracle provides has turned complex because of some terms and the lack of examples, but, as I mentioned the cube is the only one that fails, the dimensiones load correctly.

As an extra, we are using docker to install the image of the database.

Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: sufficient code to be able to replicate the issue; and the expected output. At the moment, you have provided a single screenshot and an error message which is not enough to replicate the issue.
